# how to avoid from ajax call same function with .scroll(function() if i was click on another div with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

in this code you can see that i have two div tags that every one of them have not the same onclick="" function call,
the problem is when i click on one of them and then click on enother one the  .scroll(function() works also from the first clicked function,
this example with alert only,

```
<div class="first_div_class" onclick="firstFunction();">First Div</div>
<div class="second_div_class" onclick="secondFunction();">Second Div</div>
<div class="result"></div>
<script class="functions">

        function firstFunction(){

          var one = '<?php echo $someValueOne; ?>';
          var two = '<?php echo $someValueTwo; ?>';                      

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        url:'getSomethingOne.php',
                        data: {
                            'SomethingOneInFirstFunction':one,
                            'SomethingTwoInFirstFunction':two
                        },
                       
                        success:function(data){
                            
                $('.result').html(data);

                                         },
        
            });
            
            $('.result').scroll(function(){
   

                                  alert("Hello! to the first box!!");

            });
            
        }

        function secondFunction(){
    
          var one = '<?php echo $someValueOne; ?>';
          var two = '<?php echo $someValueTwo; ?>';   
                
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        url:'getSomethingTwo.php',
                        data: {
                            'SomethingOneInSecondFunction':one,
                            'SomethingTwoInSecondFunction':two
                        },
                       
                        success:function(data){
                            
                $('.result').html(data);

                                         },
        
            });
            
            $('.result').scroll(function(){
   

                                  alert("Hello! to the second box!!");

            });
            
        }
</script>
```

even if you will try without the ajax call and only with on click function its will continue the first clicked function scroll call,

how can i stop this?...

Comment: so unbind the event if you no longer want it

Comment: Java has NOTHING to do with JavaScript

Comment: epascarello
 how to unbind the event?

Comment: @epascarello unbind (per-se) is deprecated as of 3.0 in favor of `.off()`

Comment: Stop using `on*` inline handlers like `onclick`. JS should be in one place only and that's its respective tag or file. Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your listener [for one-time usage](https://api.jquery.com/one/). The problem is that you are setting a new scroll handler for the same HTML element on every call of your function and they are never removed.

```
$('.result').one('scroll', function() {...})
```

Answer (score -2):

i was added to the start of each function

```
$(".result").unbind();
```

thank you epascarello

Comment: Well, you were too quick in *just* using `.unbind()` without reading the DOCS: https://api.jquery.com/unbind/ . As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind()  **is deprecated** in favor of `.off()`. Also, rather use `$('.result').on("scroll", function(){` instead of `$('.result').scroll(function(){`